# Save openVPN password using network manager

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, openvpn, mate

I'm using network manager on Ubuntu 12.04, with Mate as a desktop.

The network manager is used to connect to the openVPN server.
Each time I click to connect to the openVPN server, I'm required to type in a password.

Is there a way to save this openVPN password, so I don't have to write it each time. Especially since it is different from by sudo password, so sometimes I type in the wrong one.

Comment: 12.04 is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.

Comment: @bbaja42 Are you still looking for a solution to this? Does it apply to current releases of Ubuntu?